# scala for every first element in a list of tuples get max of the second element

Tags: scala, list, unique

I have a list of tuples like below

```
List((a,1), (a,2), (b,2), (b,1))
```

I want to create a List like below from that above list

```
List((a,2), (b,2))
```

Only one first element and MAX of the second element. How can I do this concisely?

Comment: Trying this 

    list.groupBy(_._1).map { case (common, lst) => (common, lst.reduce(_ max _)) }

Comment: So, what problems did you encounter when you tried it?

Comment: @Dima Pressed return before I entered my full comment. This is what I am getting when I tried

error: value max is not a member of (String, Int)

Comment: This worked 

myList.groupBy(_._1).map {case (common, lst) => lst.maxBy(_._2) }.toList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need the 1st elements of same value once along with the max value of the corresponding 2nd element, it's no difference from rephrasing the question as `for every distinct 1st element in the tuple list, list the max 2nd element`:

```
val l = List(("a",1), ("a",2), ("b",2), ("b",1))

l.groupBy(_._1).
  mapValues( _.map(_._2).max ).
  toList
// res1: List[(String, Int)] = List((b,2), (a,2))
```

Comment: Perfect. Even better.